# Ansible ignoring conditional

Tags: ansible

I am working on a ansible playbook for my servers (mix of ubuntu and centos) and when trying to transfer some config files for monit if a program is installed I am running into an issue. It works perfectly on my centos machines but the ubuntu one's it transfers the template no matter what completely ignoring the conditional.

```
---
- name: Check for Sendmail (Ubuntu)
  shell: dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\n' sendmail
  register: ubuntu_installed
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
  changed_when: False
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in ubuntu_installed.stderr"

- debug: var=ubuntu_installed

- name: Check for Sendmail (CentOs)
  shell: rpm -qa | grep sendmail
  register: cent_installed
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
  changed_when: False
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in cent_installed.stderr"

- name: Transfer Monit config files for Sendmail (Ubuntu)
  template: src=monit/templates/sendmail.j2 dest=/etc/monit/conf.d/sendmail owner=root group=root mode=644
  when: ubuntu_installed.skipped is not defined and ubuntu_installed.stdout != "" and ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

- name: Transfer Monit config files for Sendmail (CentOs)
  template: src=monit/templates/sendmail.j2 dest=/etc/monit.d/sendmail owner=root group=root mode=644
  when: cent_installed.skipped is not defined and cent_installed.stdout != "" and ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
```

I have the debug in there to check to make sure the variable is right. When I run the playbook I get...

```
TASK: [monit | debug var=ubuntu_installed] ************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "item": "",
    "ubuntu_installed": {
        "changed": false,
        "cmd": "dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\\n' sendmail ",
        "delta": "0:00:00.012985",
        "end": "2014-07-11 16:56:12.688509",
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\\n' sendmail",
            "module_name": "shell"
        },
        "item": "",
        "rc": 1,
        "start": "2014-07-11 16:56:12.675524",
        "stderr": "dpkg-query: no packages found matching sendmail",
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```

It is completely ignoring the conditional `ubuntu_installed.stdout != ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your conditional:

```
-  when: ubuntu_installed.skipped is not defined and ubuntu_installed.stdout != "" and ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
```

Your [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is incorrect: A and B and C or D means is (A and B and C) or D, which is not what you want. (note [Ansible conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) use [Jinja2 expressions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#expressions), which reflect Python conditionals, so [here are the precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)).

Lazy programmers add parenthesis for clarity; here's the revised conditional:

```
-  when: (ubuntu_installed.skipped is not defined and ubuntu_installed.stdout != "") and (ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu')
```

PS- you showed the output to one command, `debug`, but it's helpful to give alllll the output. That's `ansible-playbook -vvv`.

Comment: Also
     (ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu')
could be collapsed into
     (ansible_os_family == 'Debian')